# How can I automate google docs with Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-docs-api

Listmates:

I am designing a google app engine (python) app to automate law office documents.

I plan on using GAE, google docs, and google drive to create and store the finished documents.   My plan is to have case information (client name, case number, etc.) entered and retrieved using GAE web forms and the google datastore. Then I will allow the user to create a motion or other document by inserting the form data into template.

The completed document can be further customized by the user, email, printed, and/or stored in a google drive folder.

I found information on how to create a web page that can be printed.  However, I am looking for information for how to create an actual google doc and insert the form data into that document or template.

Can someone point me to a GAE tutorial of any type that steps me through how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API to create google docs directly except for:
1) make a google apps script service, which does have access to the docs api.
2) create a ".doc" then upload and convert to gdoc.

1 is best but a gas service has some limitations like quotas. If you are only creating dozens/hundreds per day you will be ok with quotas. Ive done it this way for something similar as your case.